# Wicket form submit data loss

Tags: forms, validation, wicket

We have a problem at our login page which has a form using post method, The problem is that sometimes post parameters comes null to server but they are not null. Form validators behave like parameters are not entered. I put my form code below. Do you have any idea or intuition ?

```
protected class LoginForm extends OurForm {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5813819309808445973L;

    public LoginForm(String id) {
        super(id);

        setDefaultModel(new CompoundPropertyModel<Map<Object , Object>>(iMap));
        TextField<String> userId=new TextField<String>("USERCODE" , String.class);
        userId.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        userId.setRequired(true);
        add(userId);

        PasswordTextField password = new PasswordTextField("USERPASSWORD");
        password.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        password.setRequired(true);
        add(password);

        add(new SubmitLink("SUBMIT"));
    }
```

The html form code generated by wicket :

```
<form autocomplete="off" id="id2" method="post" action=";jsessionid=989511050F24C577A23CF7CC55BC9757.salacakEUPT?x=UYCQLoTt3sXylAFd5u7DPGpiOKN9Mx4oErlMwLtbLndItHXg9LDIrg"><div style="width:0px;height:0px;position:absolute;left:-100px;top:-100px;overflow:hidden"><input type="hidden" name="id2_hf_0" id="id2_hf_0" /></div>
<table width="100%">
<tr><td colspan="3"><h2>&nbsp; </h2></td></tr>
<tr><td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="80%">
<table width="100%">
<tr><td colspan="2" height="100">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" width="50%"><label class="label" >Kullanıcı Kodu</label></td>
<td align="left" width="50%"><input type="text" value="" name="USERCODE" id="id3"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><label class="label" >Şifre</label></td>
<td align="left" ><input type="password" value="" name="USERPASSWORD" id="id4"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" height="20">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" id="id5" onclick="var wcall=euptWicketSubmitFormById('id2', ';jsessionid=989511050F24C577A23CF7CC55BC9757.salacakEUPT?x=UYCQLoTt3sXylAFd5u7DPIvNsZm6zLH4Nn8IO6OcpRl09M**bsF1rsqDb-hhJWazVdFfqhn-IWmQiM30HCroAnex3YAslQLnMwTnZBT5fO6Cuav6A95RGA', 'SUBMIT' ,function() { }.bind(this),function() { }.bind(this), function() {return Wicket.$$(this)&amp;&amp;Wicket.$$('id2')}.bind(this));;; return false;" submitlink="true" value="Giriş"/></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" height="100">&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
<td width="10%"></td></tr></table>
</form>
```

**NOTE : This problem occurs sometimes not everytime.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIK, the form components do not get processed until the form's `onSubmit()` method is called.  I typically persist my data at this step by calling somthing along the lines of:

```
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit() {
        Item item = (Item) getModelObject();
        dao.storeItem(item);
        setResponsePage(page);
    }
```

I am not familiar with `SubmitLink("id")`, so I can not tell you why that is not working.  This method above should work as long as your OurForm class has the same behavior as org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.  Your validation also should not check the component inputs until the `onSubmit()` method is called.  Also, seba is right that you should use Model or PropertyModel in the constructor of your TextFields.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the Model that belongs to the Form? I mean in Wicket you basically always work with Models, you never access the raw Post data. In your example Form there is simply no Model defined at all. That is rather strange. I would recommend using a Model.

For example this is our SignInForm:
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/openmeetings/trunk/singlewebapp/src/org/apache/openmeetings/web/pages/auth/

It assigns the params using a PropertyModel.

Sebastian

Comment: We use compoundpropertymodel the line in the code is this.    setDefaultModel(new CompoundPropertyModel<Map<Object , Object>>(iMap));

Comment: All our pages uses this model we reach the component values over a map

Comment: your code snippet does not show how you read the result of the form processing.

Comment: I put the critical code snippet, the other code of the page is not related to the topic. Our form code has constructor and overriden execute method which is invoked when validators accept the request. But when null parameters send execute method is not invoked. In fact the problem is about the html created by wicket. If you want i can show html generated by wicket